# Memory errors when calling variable

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm getting different errors that are always related to the memory (this current set throws memory violation exception) when I pass a pointer to a function.
I tried various implementations to solve the problem but nothing worked.
Here is the code:
*In class:*

```
class OpenFileDialog {
public:
  OpenFileDialog();
  ~OpenFileDialog();
  static bool BrowseFiles(wstring* fileName) {
    OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
    //ZeroMemory(fileName,sizeof(fileName));
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = _T("All\0*.*\0Text\0*.txt\0");
    ofn.lpstrFile = LPWSTR((*fileName).c_str());
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = _T("Select a File!");
    ofn.Flags = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
    if (GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}};
```

*Method calling:*

```
try {
    wstring fileName;
    if (OpenFileDialog::BrowseFiles(&fileName)) {
        A(fileName); // erros here
    } else {
        A(_T("Failed"));
    }
} catch (bad_alloc) {
    A(L"Bad allocation");
}
```

Comment: And what is `A`?

Comment: Just a function that prints the passing variable in a messageBox. However, thats not the issue since. I used the function multiple times.

Comment: The debugger stack trace is very important.  GetOpenFileName() and friends are risky, they load shell extensions in your process.  Programmer machines tend to have a lot of them, not always of the best quality.  If one of them misbehaves then the debugger will see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast `LPWSTR((*fileName).c_str())` should be a hint that you do something wrong.

The string `fileName` is *empty*, it doesn't have any memory allocated for it. Calling `c_str()` will return a pointer to a ***constant*** string of zero characters.

So there are two errors: You try to write data to memory that doesn't exist; And even if it did it would be constant and not modifiable anyway. Both leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to create a temporary array of characters, large enough to hold the longest path possible, and then initialize `fileName` to that string after `GetOpenFileNameW` succeeds.

Comment: SO users tend to post the last version of the code they tried.  It was the only "memory error" cause he could think of.  It ain't it.

Comment: A temporary C-style character array is not needed. `fileName->resize(MAX_PATH); ofn.lpstrFile = fileName->data();`. This requires C++17 for non-const `data()`. C++11 allows for `fileName->resize(MAX_PATH); ofn.lpstrFile = &fileName[0];`. Valid, but less clean.